# difference between dateTime field and dateTime.Now in sql

Tags: sql, datetime, datediff

I want to create a query for this purpose:

Delete from my table [tblTempBlackList] where the difference between its dateTime field and dateTime.Now is more than 240 minutes.

I tried this query but didnt work:

```
DELETE FROM [tblTempBlackList] 
WHERE (SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, (SELECT [tblTempBlackList].BlackListDateTime 
                                FROM [tblTempBlackList] 
                                WHERE MobileNumber = '') , GETDATE()
                      )
      ) > '240'`
```

Comment: You say 240 minutes, but you compare to a 480 string?

Comment: you are right, I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM tblTempBlackList
WHERE 
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, (SELECT [tblTempBlackList].BlackListDateTime FROM [tblTempBlackList] WHERE MobileNumber = ''), GETDATE()) > 240
```

Or, even more concisely:

```
DELETE FROM tblTempBlackList
WHERE 
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, BlackListDateTime, GetDate()) > 240
AND MobileNumber = ''
```

Comment: Your second query makes more sense +1 .

Comment: @shree.pat18 Thanks for your answer, but Subquery returned more than 1 value. I have more than 1 field with MobileNumber = '' that I want to delete all of them with above condition.

Comment: The second query should work I believe. The first will certainly run into the subquery error.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
DECLARE @DeleteBefore DATETIME = DATEADD(MINUTE, -240, GETDATE())

DELETE FROM [tblTempBlackList]
WHERE
  BlackListDateTime < @DeleteBefore
  AND MobileNumber = ''
```